# Segmentation Fault gcc-4.9.1.RHEL6.4/include/c++/4.9.1/backward/auto_ptr.h:184

Tags: boost

I am using Boost 1.56.0 for its dijkstra_shortest_paths in a c++ program (redhead 4.9.1, std = c++11). Somehow, I keep getting the following segmentation fault error in auto_ptr.h: 184

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
std::auto_ptr<boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> >::operator* (this=) at /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.1.RHEL6.4/include/c++/4.9.1/backward/auto_ptr.h:184
(gdb) bt
#0  std::auto_ptr<boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> >::operator* (this=) at /opt/devl/optimize/gcc-4.9.1.RHEL6.4/include/c++/4.9.1/backward/auto_ptr.h:184
#1  boost::detail::sep_<unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> >::get_property (this=) at /usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:278
#2  boost::detail::out_edge_iter<std::_List_iterator<boost::detail::sep_<unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> > >, unsigned long, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, unsigned long>, long>::dereference (this=) at /usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:152
#3  boost::iterator_core_access::dereference<boost::detail::out_edge_iter<std::_List_iterator<boost::detail::sep_<unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> > >, unsigned long, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, unsigned long>, long> > (f=...) at /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:516
#4  boost::iterator_facade<boost::detail::out_edge_iter<std::_List_iterator<boost::detail::sep_<unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> > >, unsigned long, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, unsigned long>, long>, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, unsigned long>, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, unsigned long>, long>::operator* (this=) at /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:634
#5  boost::breadth_first_visit<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<unsigned long, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<unsigned long*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long>, unsigned long, unsigned long&>, int*, std::less<int>, std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > >, boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<boost::null_visitor>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<unsigned long, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<unsigned long*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long>, unsigned long, unsigned long&>, int*, std::less<int>, std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double const&, unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> const, boost::edge_weight_t>, unsigned long*, int*, boost::closed_plus<int>, std::less<int> >, boost::two_bit_color_map<boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long> > > (g=..., s=0, Q=..., vis=..., color=...) at /usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:77
#6  boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_init<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::dijkstra_visitor<boost::null_visitor>, unsigned long*, int*, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double const&, unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> const, boost::edge_weight_t>, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long>, std::less<int>, boost::closed_plus<int>, int, boost::two_bit_color_map<boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long> > > (g=..., s=0, predecessor=, distance=, weight=..., index_map=..., 
    compare=..., combine=..., zero=0, vis=..., color=...) at /usr/include/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:332
#7  boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::dijkstra_visitor<boost::null_visitor>, unsigned long*, int*, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double const&, unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> const, boost::edge_weight_t>, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long>, std::less<int>, boost::closed_plus<int>, int, int, boost::two_bit_color_map<boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long> > > (g=..., s=0, predecessor=, distance=, weight=..., index_map=..., 
    compare=..., combine=..., inf=2147483647, zero=0, vis=..., color=...) at /usr/include/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:383
#8  boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::dijkstra_visitor<boost::null_visitor>, unsigned long*, int*, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double const&, unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> const, boost::edge_weight_t>, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long>, std::less<int>, boost::closed_plus<int>, int, int, int*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<unsigned long*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > (g=..., s=0, predecessor=, distance=, weight=..., 
    index_map=..., compare=..., combine=..., inf=2147483647, zero=0, vis=...) at /usr/include/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:353
#9  boost::detail::dijkstra_dispatch2<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, int*, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double const&, unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> const, boost::edge_weight_t>, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long>, boost::bgl_named_params<int*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<unsigned long*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > > (g=..., s=0, distance=, weight=..., index_map=..., params=...) at /usr/include/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:423
#10 boost::detail::dijkstra_dispatch1<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, int*, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double const&, unsigned long, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property> const, boost::edge_weight_t>, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsigned long>, boost::bgl_named_params<int*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<unsigned long*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > > (g=..., s=0, distance=, weight=..., index_map=..., params=...) at /usr/include/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:455
#11 boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, int*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<unsigned long*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > (g=..., s=0, params=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:473
```

Would greatly appreciate it very much if you could help pointing out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you forgot to include any code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere you are using `auto_ptr<>`.

This type has been deprecated (for the reason that it's hardly possible to use it right and rarely safe). In particular: you can *never* use it inside standard libraries containers (because it fails readonly copy semantics).

Assuming you really need pointers there (why do you?) you should probably use ptr_vector, ptr_set etc. from the Boost Pointer Container library, or use a modern smart pointer (unique_ptr, value_ptr, scoped_ptr, shared_ptr
)

Comment: Thank you Sehe!
Here is the code snippet that gets me into trouble for the segmentation fault when executed. It is nothing but a copy of an example that you find in boost for the dijkstra shortest path. Once the call is made, the program crashes. And when I do a backtrack it shows this auto_ptr<> is being used. Not sure if Boost uses it or what, but that's where I am hoping to get help from people like you. 
Again, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Mark Did you mean to include a link? Or edit the question. Because I'm not seeing any code snippet

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it posted (was too long):
 int nodeSize = (int) m_allNodeList.size();
  graph_t g( m_allArcList.begin(), m_allArcList.end(), m_arcWeights.begin(), nodeSize);
  property_map<graph_t, edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = get(edge_weight, g);
  std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
  std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));
  vertex_descriptor s = vertex(0, g);

  graph_traits < graph_t >::edge_iterator ei;
  graph_traits < graph_t >::edge_iterator ei_end;\
  //at the following call, core dumped. 
  dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s, predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));

Comment: @Mark You can edit the question. Also, you can reduce the code to the minimum relevant :/